# Online documentation explaining tags output by Stanford NLP parser?

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

is there any online documentation explaining tags output by Stanford NLP parser?

I'm quite new to NLP and and to me it seems that the tags like NN, VBZ, .. and relationships like poss, nsubj ... seem to follow a kind of standard since I've seen this output on other parsers.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For grammatical dependencies (nsubj, poss...), you can read the official manual: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf

Tags like NN, VBZ... are part-of-speech tags. You can find info about them here: https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html, or by googling "part-of-speech tags penn treebank"

Answer (score 2):

The answer given by @permanganate already provides the best (to my knowledge) list of part-of-speech tags defined in the Penn Treebank. For the dependency tags, however, I find the following Stanford Twiki page far more useful than the more commonly used manual:

[Stanford Dependencies Twiki](https://wiki.inf.ed.ac.uk/TFlex/StanfordDependencies)

It provides a neat representation of the entire hierarchy, followed by detailed examples of many tags that are not explained in the manual. I have found these illustrative examples to be very helpful, even when I am using other (non-Stanford) dependency parsers.